# React Native - pass class to component as props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible in React Native to pass class to a custom component as props and then call the methods of that class into the component?

Here's my supposed code.

```js
import MyAwesomeClass from './model.js';
...
...
...
<MyComponent model=myAwesomeClass />
```

model.js

```js
export default class MyAwesomeClass {
    var name;
    var surname;
    function getName(){
        return name;
    }
    function getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
}
```

And then call the class methods like this:

MyComponent.js

```js
export default class myComponent extends Component {
    ...
    ...
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.getName()}></Text>
                <Text>{this.props.getSurname()}></Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I know that I could pass directly `name` and `surname` as props and get them into `myComponent` using `this.props.name` and `this.props.surname` but I would like to pass an entire class instead of sigle properties. 
Is this possible in React Native? If not, what is the best practice to realise something like this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, this will work if you do things correctly. Not really a Javascript way, though. Why don't you simply pass a `{name, surname}` object? You will be able to access the properties directly anyway.

Comment: passing that object I should access the properties with something like `this.props.myplainjsobject.name` ?

Comment: Yep. At the end of the day a javascript class is just a dressed up javascript object anyway. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are the mozilla docs on javascript classes.

Comment: Then I think I'll use a plain js object instead a class. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Cleaning up your class,

```js
export default class MyAwesomeClass {
    constructor(name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
   // ... any methods here
}
```

Then make sure you instantiate the class, e.g.

```
const bob = new MyAwesomeClass('Bob', 'the Builder');
```

Now you can access `name` and `surname` directly,

```
console.log(bob.name)
>>> 'Bob'
```

Comment: And can I pass the bob constant as prop to myComponent?

Comment: Yep! You could also just do an object `bob` that has the keys `name` and `surname` if you don't need to anything else fancy with your data, like @Sulthan mentioned.